# Ping Failure When Trying To Connect to MySql Databse Using Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

So I am having a problem setting up a new connection within eclipse so that I can convert a current Maven project into a JPA project. I have a MySql database set up and can access it with WinSql. However, I get a ping failure when I try and connect with Eclipse using the New Connection Profile. All of the info is the same in the fields. I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar added to my build path so I really don't know what else could be the problem. When the ping fails it gives me the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Connection failed with unspecified error.
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:110)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? I've looked around for a few hours and see a lot of similar questions but nothing seems to work. One other thing that might be important is that the  MySql server is hosted on my universites server so I need to connect through a VPN to access it. I do this with Cisco AnyConnect and have no problems connecting with WinSql.

Comment: You have not shown the important bits, specifically how you have configured Eclipse's connection profile.  Also have you verified that you can telnet to port 3306 and get a connection?

Comment: @JimGarrison I am not able to telnet port 3306. I'll be honest and tell you that I'm not sure what it means.   Also, by Eclipse Connection Profile do you mean the Database name, URL, etc?

Comment: @JimGarrison In my Eclipse Connection Profile I have the following info shown in this photo:  http://imgur.com/OODtm9s

Comment: Have you tried to use the sql client from the command line to make sure you can connect?

Comment: your url doesnot seems correct to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I ran into this same problem now almost exactly a year later. Google brought me back to my own question and now I have the solution so I figured I would give an answer.

I was using an incorrect URL for the connection. The correct URL is jdbc:mysql://yourURLhere. I had forgotten the 'mysql' and the '//' are needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It might be already running on machine before launching web application itself.Stop that process before running this

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into this error and solution is:- 
Try using path like jdbc:mysql:~/testdb. Here ~ refers to the user’s home directory location 
or you can use the custom path like 
jdbc:mysql:file:///C:Users/Project1/db/testdb